# How can I push my ASP.NET MVC web-application to webserver

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-code, iis, webserver

i created a web-app in vscode using MySQL and ASP.NET MVC.
Now i want to publish my project in a webserver or IIS.

What is the best opportunity and how can i push it to the server/IIS ??

Need todo this, so other users in the network have access to the webapp

Comment: Please describe what you have tried so far. What are the issues you are facing. Otherwise this question will not meet the question requirement of Stackoverflow.
FYI, here is one of the many ways to publish: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc5-deployment-on-windows-iis-server/

Comment: ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core?

Comment: @LexLi ASP.NET Framework

Comment: @Rahatur didnt try yet - because dont know how. I would like to get a guide or an answer to which webserver so i can research. And is it possible with vscode code or only vs2019

Comment: @Rahatur thanks for the link, but this is for VisualStudio2019 and not for VisualStudioCode. Can u send for VScode, didnt found sth..

Comment: vscode is essentially a text editor, it does not integrate many functions like vs. So using it to publish projects requires the help of other extensions. You can use Task Run to publish. Refeter to this answer about using it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40856600/14162739

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS web server didn´t work for me in combination with mysql database on a running Linux system.

U can try to push it on linux with apache: this is explained here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-6.0 But i was facing problems with proxy server.

Currently I am trying it in connection with a FTP-server.

The easiest way should be a cloud system, like azure oder aws.

Good Luck :) Please comment other solutions below.